# Unable to Pass Glue Job arguments from Step Function input that is set using startExecution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I am trying pass argument to Glue job from step functions and the variable is not getting resolved. Here is my code.
I have only one step in my state machine, which is as below.

```
{
  "Comment": "Test Function",
  "StartAt": "StartGlueJob",
  "States": {
    "StartGlueJob": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "my-job-name",
        "Arguments": {
          "--output": "$.outputpath"
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling the step function from Lambda using boto3 and my code is as below:

```
stepclient.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:XXXX:XXXX:stateMachine:MyStateMachine',
        name=funcation_name,
        input="{\"outputpath\": \"new-sr-out\"}"
        )
```

I want to pass value for --output all the way from lambda till glue job. But, the value is not getting resolved.

Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use JsonPath in `Parameters`, the key needs to end in `.$`.

See the section on Payload Template in the ASL spec: https://states-language.net/#payload-template